# Algorithm to place images next to stories in a constrained 4-column newspaper grid

Tags: algorithm, layout, printing, bin-packing

This question is about any code or pointer that facilitates layout of images "near" to stories within a constrained and well-defined grid.

These are the basics and inputs:

- The entire object is called a newspaper. It has a set of stories (of varying text length)
- Each story can either have an image associated to it, or not
- The newspaper is laid out into 4 columns automatically. Text flows from top left to bottom right, down each column
- Images can be placed into fixed positions - top left, top centre, top right, left centre, centre, right centre, bottom left, bottom centre, bottom right
- When an image is placed, it can span between 1 to 3 columns. The height is automatically adjusted to fit the proportions, based on the span which is set.
- All the actual layout work (and images flowing around the text) is done - what is required of the algorithm is the decision making only

The overall problem is to place stories in the fixed layout in an interesting way such that pictures are near to the stories associated with them, and also exhibit an interesting variation of position and span, so as to make the printed reading experience interesting and aesthetically pleasing.

This is the work required of the algorithm:

- When a story with a picture is placed into the newspaper, at least
  one edge of the picture must touch the story which it relates to.
- We need to decide whether or not to re-order the stories so that the image density is not too biased in one area e.g. the first 4 pages have lots of pictures and the rest of the newspaper is just text.
- If we choose to re-order and shuffle stories, then what is the optimal approach to resolving this placement problem?

In general, I'm not sure if this falls under the bin-packing problem - in the sense that stories can be re-ordered to minimise white-space; because we need images to be placed "near" to stories.

Any pointers to how to approach this problem, or code that facilitates a similar class of problem is appreciated.

Comment: What is the average and range of numbers of stories per page? Pictures per page?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that an ordering of stories will have those stories text appearing one after another in column order. If the story has a picture then the picture could be above/below/left/or right of the story text

1. Generate all possible orders of stories and pictures
2. Discard the order if any picture position won't fit (it can't be to the left of the leftmost column, or if placed where specified, the picture doesn't end up in one of the allowed locations).

You are left with a set of possible story/picture orders that fit the placement rules. You might then display them in miniature and have sub-editors choose the best.